# Add Footer for whole Android Application

Tags: android, footer

In my application I have a footer for each `activity`. Basically I have an `ImageView` in footer which get Images (adds Images) from `Web service` and change images after some time interval (like sliding adds). What I am doing is adding footer in each activity and call web service in every activity to load images into `ImageView` (which is going to be a very heavy processing for my app because I have many `Java classes(Activities)` in my app), so my question is...
Is there any way in android that I can add footer for whole application? like if I add a footer in `first activity` at bottom, now if I move to `second activity, third activity` and so on....the footer will still there which I've added in the `first activity`. (same like in iPhone `Navigation controller` is used )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your view programatically then store it in a singleton object which can be accessed throughout the application, this will avoid having to create a new View each time.

Singleton class example:

```
public class MySingleFooter{
MySingleFooter mySingleFooter;
View myFooter;

private MySingleFooter(){}

public static MySingleFooter getInstance()
{
if (mySingleFooter == null)
    {
    mySingleFooter = new MySingleFooter();
    }

return mySingleFooter;
}

void setFooter(View myFooter)
{
    this.myFooter = myFooter;
}

View getFooter()
{
    return myFooter;
}}
```

You can set the footer from all activities like this:

`MySingleFooter footerStore = MySingleFooter.getInstance();
footerStore.setFooter(thefooter);`

You can retrieve the footer from all activities like this:

`MySingleFooter footerStore = MySingleFooter.getInstance();
View myview = footerStore.getFooter(thefooter);`

Then add it to the current activity programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Make one footer xml file which you want to display on all screens of your application then follow below steps:

Create One Footer.java Activity

```
public class Footer extends Activity {
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.footer);
        }
 }
```

Then extend that class on another class for use like below:

```
public class Test extends Footer 
{
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata);
            ViewGroup.inflate(Home.this, R.layout.test, vg);
        }
}
```